# Invoke SSIS package with 32-bit from enterprise management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Is it possible to invoke an SSIS package from SQL Server Enterprise management studio using the 32 bit run-time WITHOUT using an SQL Server Agent Job (i.e. using the the Execute Package utility)?

I know it is possible to do this using the Agent Job and in Visual Studio by setting the Run64BitRuntime to false.

Comment: It can be done in SSMS using an Integration Services connection.  Is that all you need?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need.  How can I do this?  Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, open an Integration Services connection to your SSIS database, open the "Stored Packages" tree, and drill down to the package you want to execute.   Right-click on the package and choose "Run Package".   This will load the Execute Package Utility, where you can set parameters and execute the package.

Comment: Hi, Tab,Thank you for your reply.  I agree this can be done, but can it be done using the 32-bit runtime as specified in my question?  I do not see an option to set the 32 bit runtime in this dialog.

Comment: I don't see an option to actually set it. :-)

Comment: No idea.   Why do you need to use the 32 bit runtime?   Maybe there's another way to solve your bigger issue?

Comment: Because the system only has the oracle 32 bit drivers on it, so the data connection has to be loaded using the 32 bit drivers.  No, installing the 64 bit drivers is not an option.

Comment: Also, did you downvote my question, and if so, why?  It is a valid question, I've spent at least a couple of hours trying to do this.

Comment: No it wasn't me that downvoted.  I'm afraid I don't know the answer of how to set it to use 32-bit..my best guess is either a server-level setting or registry entry.

Comment: When I right click / execute, I can see the '32-bit runtime' tickbox on the Advanced tab. What do you see on your Advanced tab?

Comment: Failing that you could cook up an SP to start the package and right click on the SP and run it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database